# I am making glass for a phone camera, making lens invisible

Tags: glass

I'm making a phone animation, but when I make the glass, the lens, under the glass, which is made out of the same material disappears. Image--->

[image: Top Without glass]
[image: And this is the camera with glass]

Comment: Maybe the lens should have some curvature?

Comment: Lens is a circle, cant see from above

Comment: well... change its material or change its shape (lences are not flat).

Comment: Switch to Cycles Engine.